# Changing the size of Language Switcher block in D7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have been trying to reduce the width and height of language switcher block in D7 but failed to find the corresponding CSS file.

[image: The dotted is the block size, how to make it fit for the dropdown menu only?]

Answer (score 3):

Just overwrite it with your styles. Don't mess with core files.

Answer (score 1):

As "ghyjek" specified, you can overwrite it with your own CSS. But this depends on the order in which your CSS files are loaded. If your CSS file is loaded in the end, you don't need to do anything as it will override it anyways.

If not, you will need to specify more specific selectors to override it. Following is a sample example:-

> .someElementClass { width: 10px; height: 10px; } // Drupal default CSS
>
> .bodyClass .someElementClass { width: 10px; height: 10px; } // In your CSS file

Here the second one will override the first one. Also you need to make sure not to mess up with the Drupal's core CSS file as specified by "ghyjek"

Thanks.

Comment: If not sure, use !important. Example `.someElementClass { width: 10px; height: 10px; !important } // In your CSS file`